# create blob from content of a variable in logic app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I would like to create a blob from content of a variable like this:
[image]

but in blob content property I can not chose my variable `Set variable 2`.

what should I do to do this job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be related to the variable type you defined. After testing, variables of `Object` type and `Array` type will cause the problems you encounter.

You can try to use [string expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#string) to solve your problem:

[image]

Expression:

```
string(variables('<your-variable-name>'))
```